# 2 PlaceHolder inside Repeater - Hide/Show

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, repeater

I am trying to hide PlaceHolder2 and show PlaceHolder1 - on click of linkButton. Both are insider repeater.

**Aspx**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
   <asp:Repeater ID="rptOnly" runat="server">
         <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server" Visible="False">
                      //Display some images
              </asp:PlaceHolder>
              <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder2" runat="server">
                   <asp:linkbutton runat="server" id="lnkbtn" text="Click Here" OnClick="Myfunction_Click" />
              </asp:PlaceHolder>
         </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:Repeater>
</form>
```

**VB.net**

```
Protected Sub Myfunction_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    PlaceHolder1.Visible = True
    PlaceHolder2.Visible = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use FindControl from the RepeaterItem (as there could be multiple items in the Repeater) and then set the visibility.

EX for First Item in Repeater =

```
CType(rptOnly.Items(0).FindControl("PlaceHolder1"), PlaceHolder).Visible = True
CType(rptOnly.Items(0).FindControl("PlaceHolder2"), PlaceHolder).Visible = False
```

For all items in the repeater, do a For Each RPI as RepeaterItem in rptOnly.Items and do the same thing.

Edit from Comments:

Your particular issue would have you set the CommandName Property of your Button, which is also within the ItemTemplate, and change the visibility of the PlaceHolders in the ItemCommand Event of the Repeater.

```
CType(e.Item.FindControl("PlaceHolder1"), PlaceHolder).Visible = True
```

Comment: Does this have to be inside click event ?

Comment: If button is in the item template give the button's CommandName property a value and use the repeater's item command event, otherwise yes.

Comment: Sorry this doesn't work for multiple enteries in repeater. No matter what I click it always shows the first one.

Comment: Off of the Repeater Item's Command Event you use e.Item.FindControl("PlaceHolder1") so you get the correct repeater item.

Comment: Got it thanks...If you'll update your answer...I'll accept it

Answer (score 1):

The repeater has a collection of items - You need to check each item in the collection:

```
For Each c As Control in rptOnly.Items

    Dim p1 As Control = c.FindControl("PlaceHolder1")
    Dim p2 As Control = c.FindControl("PlaceHolder2")

    If p1 IsNot Nothing Then
        p1.Visible = True
    End If
    If p2 IsNot Nothing Then
        p2.Visible = False
    End If
Next
```

Each item is a RepeaterItem: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeateritem_methods(v=vs.110).aspx

In `Myfunction_Click` you should be able to find the placeholder as the control parent - something like this (you might need to cast the Parent object):

```
Protected Sub Myfunction_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    sender.Parent.Visible = True
    sender.Parent.Visible = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Does this have to be inside click event ?

Comment: :-) ah, I've converted it

Comment: Your answer is not right. `sender.parent.visible` is set to true then false ?